# Setting up loggers from a config file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, logging, configuration

I have a bunch of python scripts for my project and I want to implement logging configurations on them. So I have 2 loggers (`log1, log2`) all three have different levels, formatters and file handlers. All the loggers configurations are stored in a `Logger.conf` file to be implemented to. The purpose of having multiple loggers is to assign a logger to a certain file, some files are more important than others so depending on this hierarchy a file could be assigned `log1, or log2`. script1.py's logger will be `log1` whilst `script2.py and script3.py` will be assigned to `log2`. The configurations of `log1` and `log2` are presented down below. How can I structure the `Logger.conf` and achieve the expected logger configurations.

Configurations:

- `log1`:

  - SetLevel: DEBUG
  - Filehanler:

    - Setlevel: DEBUG
    - Formatter: `%(asctimes) - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s`
    - output: `logging.log`
  - StreamHandler:

    - Setlevel: WARNING
    - Formatter: `%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s`
    - output: `console`
- `log2`:

  - SetLevel: INFO
  - Filehanler:

    - Setlevel: INFO
    - Formatter: `%(name)s : %(message)s`
    - output: `logging.log`
  - SMTPHandler:

    - Setlevel: CRITICAL
    - Formatter: `%(levelname)s - %(message)s`
    - output emails: `['hello123@gmail.com','billyyes@gmail.com']`

Directory Tree:

```
Project Folder/
├─Logger.conf
├─Logging.log
├─script1.py
├─script2.py
└─script3.py
```

code within `script1.py, script2.py, script3.py`

```
logger.DEBUG("hi this is a debug msg")
logger.INFO("hi this is an info msg")
logger.WARNING("hi this is a warning msg")
logger.ERROR("hi this is an error msg")
logger.CRITICAL("hi this is a critical msg")
```

When the code is ran on all scripts strating from script1 and ending at script3.py the expected outputs are as follows:

Expected Output:

console:

```
log1 - WARNING - hi this is a warning msg
log1 - ERROR -hi this is an error msg
log1 - CRITICAL -hi this is a critical msg
```

logging.log:

```
JULY-02-2022 04:30:31 - log1 - DEBUG - hi this is a debug msg
JULY-02-2022 04:30:31 - log1 - INFO - hi this is an info msg
JULY-02-2022 04:30:31 - log1 - WARNING - hi this is a warning msg
JULY-02-2022 04:30:31 - log1 - ERROR - hi this is an error msg
JULY-02-2022 04:30:31 - log1 - CRITICAL - hi this is a critical msg
log2 : hi this is an info msg
log2 : hi this is a warning msg
log2 : hi this is an error msg
log2 : hi this is a critical msg
```

email:

```
CRITICAL - hi this is a critical msg
```

Comment: Have you made any attempts already?